# Observable array's can't have nested observable objects?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm new to React and Mobx. I have an observable array and it has a filed named `options`, this field's value is from server and I inited it with another observable object which will be set value later. BUT `mobx` can't detect this. How can I fix this?

```
class TestStore {
  @observable formRef;
  @observable options = [];

  @action
  setFormRef(form) {
    this.formRef = form;
  }

  @action
  setOptions(options) {
    this.options = options;
  }
}
```

```
class ListStore {
  @observable list = [];
  @action
  setList(list) {
    this.list = list;
  }

  @action
  setItems(items) {
    this.list[0].items = items;
  }
}
```

```
const listStore = new ListStore();
const store = new TestStore();

listStore.setList([
  { id: 1, text: 'hello', items: store.options }
])

store.setOptions([
  { text: '333', value: '333' },
  { text: '444', value: '444' },
])
```

This `listStore`'s items field can't be updated?

Comment: Have you tried to extend your inited properties with extendObservable? https://mobx.js.org/refguide/extend-observable.html

Comment: No, I need to set items an observable object, seems not what `extendObservable` can do? any idea how to handle it ?